# How to get values from a class that has __slots__ and _fields_?

Tags: python, c, class

I am using an API library that has the following implementaion of C code to the position and rotation in a Python program:

```
class struct_LinmathPose(Structure):
    pass

struct_LinmathPose.__slots__ = [
    'Pos',
    'Rot',
]
struct_LinmathPose._fields_ = [
    ('Pos', LinmathPoint3d),
    ('Rot', LinmathQuat),
]
```

And one of the variables is of this class. How can I get and access for example the position of this variable? LinmathPoint3d and LinmathQuat are C codes.

Comment: You can't add `__slots__` to a class after it's been defined and have it do anything useful (`__slots__` is used at the moment the class definition completes to set up the object layout and define the descriptors used to access the attributes without relying on `__dict__`). So your class doesn't have *real* `__slots__`.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are dealing with, and what exactly you want to do? The question talks about "the following implementation of C code" but only shows Python code. Neither ``__slots__`` nor ``_fields_`` are generally meaningful when used as in the code shown.

Answer (score 0):

`__slots__` (which doesn't actually work as you wrote it; it's making an unused class attribute, not actually defining slots) and `_fields_` just declare variables by string name. For `_fields_` said variables are default initialized if they're not passed to the constructor; for `__slots__` they're empty until assigned. Either way, accessing them is like any other variable; you have an instance of the class, and you do `.Pos` or the like:

```
pose = struct_LinmathPose()
pose.Pos  # Reads the attribute
```